# Invoking several methods after ordering the program closed

Tags: c#, winforms

I've got a `WinForm` Application that connects via `Net.Sockets` to another program.

When it gets closed per `X` or <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> or whatever, several routines should be processed and I need to keep the network connection until they're done.

I thought an **Application.ApplicationExit** Handler would do the trick, but as soon as I give the order the network connection is dead. Other important stuff can't be done.

My Form is closed instantaneously too, and I need that one a little longer.

Is `Application.ApplicationExit` the right tool for the job?

I put that in my Form Class that `App.Runs` from the Main method which is located in a different class.

Comment: Do you have a main form in the application that you can listen to the `Closing` event on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the `Closing` event of the form. It is called before the form is closed.

Comment: @JulianSchaefer - If you think this is the answer please mark that you are accepting it by clicking on the tick just under the numbers on the left.

Answer (score 0):

If you are having an open window, there are the event-handler `Closing` and `Closed`. The `Closing`-event is fired as soon as you click 'X', for example. Inside the method you can even decide, whether to close the window or not.

Provide an event-handler like

```
private void Form1_Closing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e){
// persist until everything is done
}
```

and associate it with the event

```
Form1.Closing += Form1_Closing;
```

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.close.aspx) for documentation.